# How do you say (adjective) you are wearing cold clothes?

Tags: meaning

In portuguese there is the word:

> Agasalhado

which is used for people who are wearing clothes for cold seasons.

I would like to know if there is an equivalent word.

"Clothed" seemed to be right, although not sure about meaning it is wearing cold clothes or just opposite of naked.

Comment: Around here we say "bundled up". As yes, "clothed" means "wearing clothes", i.e. not naked.

Comment: Is there an adjective instead of a phrasal verb for this?

Comment: Can't think of one off the top of my head. But I'll noodle on it and if I come up with something, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Sounds like weather for my "long johns", undergarments for the lower torso and my legs. In the alternative, time to don my thermal underwear. Ah, the joys of being a geriatric.

Comment: 'Cold clothes' would be clothes which are cold, rather than clothes suitable for cold weather.

Comment: @DanBron your profile does not say where "around here" is. I agree, though, "bundled up" around here too, here being Bemidji (aka Brrr-midji) Minnesota, USA, where current temperature is −18º F, −28º C.

Comment: @BrianDonovan New York City, baby. I'm told if I can make it here, I can make it anywhere. But I am having some serious doubts about whether I can make it in -18* weather, bundled up or not.

Comment: Indeed, @Spagirl; but the clothes suitable for wear on mornings like this are called "warm clothes" even though when they are doing their job properly the temperatures on their outer surfaces are quite low, and on their inner still below blood heat. (Their job is to maintain a  large difference in temperature between inside and outside, as thermal insulation.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many expressions for this. In the UK, we often use the phrase [*wrap (sb) up*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wrap-sb-up):

> **wrap (sb) up** — phrasal verb with wrap
> ​
> to dress in warm clothes, or to dress someone in warm clothes:
>
> - Wrap up well - it's cold outside.

Cambridge Dictionary

You can also use:

> - Make sure that you are wrapped up well.
> - Make sure that you are well wrapped up.
> - Stand still while I wrap you up properly.

Needless to say, it is children who are usually "wrapped up". Husbands come a poor second. Wives have to do it themselves.

Comment: Am I able to say "She is well wrapped up."? (adjective)

Comment: Of course. I'll add some more examples.

Comment: A Scots (both Scottish and Ulster Scots) variant of this is 'happed up' https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hap